# Input variables - query from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a `MySQL` database which is online and which stores results from a lot of simulations I did with an energy program. 
I would like to give users of a website the possibility to look at the results in the following way:
On the website, users have lists (like a `HTML` list) and there they can select different parameters. When all parameters are selected, the form request data from the `MySQL` database and shows it on the website.

I have looked around quite a bit.. but haven't found a way how to submit a form with `HTML`/`PHP` and request the selected parameters.

Comment: Have you sample code that you can post? What did you tried?

Comment: Have you already got the HTML form?

Comment: I haven't tried so much yet. This is how I want to have on the website: [http://jourikanters.eu/exempel-1.jpg].

Comment: This is what I used to make the form:

Answer (score 0):

you can send the parameters you want using submit method on HTML Button and use that parameter as value to query the result through database
You can refer this(http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag that will let you know when all the required parameters are selected. Once the flag gets the required value, you can submit the form values and fetch the required information.